# How to decrypt the text

Tags: zend-framework, zend-form, zend-db, zend-db-table

Thanks for previous replies

I am doing encryption and decryption for my log in authentication. i used

```
define('VECTOR', 'EXfPCW23'); //example, not the actual used VECTOR / KEY
$key = 'lolwatlolwat';
$filter = new Zend_Filter_Encrypt();
$filter->setEncryption(array('key' => $key));
$filter->setVector(VECTOR);
return $filter->filter($password);
```

this codings to encrypt the data. whenever i tried to decrypt the data, the values never be decrypted. in the above coding i changed `$filter=new Zend_Filter_Decrypt();` for the decryption. pls guide me to decrypt the encrypted value. i am new to this topic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this

```
$filter = new Zend_Filter_Decrypt('myencryptionkey');

// Set the vector with which the content was encrypted
$filter->setVector('myvector');

$decrypted = $filter->filter($encrypted);
print $decrypted;
```

Please refer

http://www.thomasweidner.com/flatpress/2009/01/14/how-to-encrypt-with-zf/